# Adding button programmatically to perform segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, segue

I am trying to create a button 'on the fly' using code, and i want that button to perform 
segue to a different controller. As far as i know, creating segue programmatically is not possible, but how can i get pass that if the created button is not on my storyboard?

This is the code for creating the button:

```
- (void)addButton:(UIView*)view inLocation:(CGPoint)point
{

    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    but.frame= CGRectMake(point.x, point.y,30,30);
    [but setTitle:@"CHOOSE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // The nilSymbol should call a method that will perform the segue
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(nilSymbol) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:but];  
}
```

Any options to do that?

Comment: I really dont think this is the same case... he had a choice over there, i am currently forced to add a button to the storyboard and not adding it programmatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Interface Builder, create a segue.
Since you can't connect the segue to the button (it doesn't exist yet), simply connect the segue to the starting ViewController.
Then, when you create the button:

```
// ....
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// ....
```

And in the someMethod:

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: This is only correct if indeed such a segue exists in the storyboard, but i dont have such a segue, the button was programmatically added...

Comment: You have to create the segue! But, because of you can't connect it to the button, you must connect it to the view controller (read my first line)