# present View controller not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Hi I am developing an application in which I am presenting new `UIViewController` using

```
[self presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and in new presented view controller I am moving back to previous view using

```
[self presentViewController:oldVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

which is my requirement as there is no guarantee that from where this view will be presented.

But the issue is that when I am presenting old view controller it goes to `viewDidLoad` but does not displays old view controller it remains on same view controller.

can anyone tell me why this is happening is any thing going wrong??

Comment: You don't go back to the previous viewcontroller by presenting it, you use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: @rckoenes: It is my requirement to use `[self presentViewController:oldVC animated:NO completion:nil];` and not `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]`

Comment: Well then you are going to run into big issues later since, `presentViewController:` will add a viewController to the current one. Thus is you will end up in a stack of view on above the other until the device runs out of memory. It is saying like I need to go down stairs but can only use the stairs that go up. And who make use `presentViewController:` a requirement, besides `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` is `presentViewController:` counterpart.

Comment: Can't we dismiss older view controller once next view controller is presented?

Comment: No since the older view is the view presenting the new view.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your requirement? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @GoGreen: I need to go to previous view based on certain conditions like, if(flag==1) goto some back to view1 else go back to older view controller. like wise I am having conditions based on which I need to switch between view controllers

Comment: and do you want to retain those values in your previous view?

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: No its not compulsory to retain values in previous view

Comment: @VineeshTP yes I am using storyboard

Comment: @ShitalTiwari : How you are viewController Onject can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't go back to the previous view controller by `presentViewController:`, because it may cause a never ending loop and if user do so then your app will crash sooner or later.
But if that animation is required (i.e. animating from bottom to up), then you can make your own dismissViewController method, which will animate your oldVC from bottom to up and in completion block of that animation call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for my problem!
Instead of using `presentViewController:` and `dismissViewController:` methods, I have created segue and asked application to perform segue programmatically as per flow needed based on identifier of segue. found solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241276/1882781

Answer (score 0):

Just a pointer. The segue method will work for sure. But if you are using this method to present `view controller`s **modally**, then the previous `view controller`s will remain in `memory` until you manually `dismiss` them. 
This will lead to severe `memory` issues with app usage.

A better alternative, even though not the best, is to get a handle of the `AppDelegate` **single shared instance**, and to set its `rootViewController` to be your presented `viewController`.

eg:-

```
yourViewControllerClassName *sampleVC = [[yourViewControllerClassName alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:sampleVC animated:YES completion:^{
    yourAppDelegateClassName *appdelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appdelegate.window.rootViewController = sampleVC;
}];
```

This will deallocate the existing `viewController` object from memory.

**PS:** Make sure to import the `appdelegate.h` file in all the classes, or you can alternatively write this in the **.pch** file.

Hope this helps! :)