# Xcode Segue "Could not cast value of type"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have segues going to two different ViewControllers, Detail & Search. The segues going to Detail are working fine, but the one going to Search keeps crashing the app. I have spent two hours reading similar questions but none of them seem to have the same issue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController

    if segue.identifier == "newDocSegue"   {
        // Create a new document and pass it to the detail view.
        detailVC.doc = Document()
        detailVC.isAddAction = true
    }

    if segue.identifier == "editDocSegue"    {
        // Load the existing document into the detail view, for editing.
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        detailVC.doc = Document[indexPath.row]
        detailVC.isAddAction = false
    }
     else if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
        shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender: Any?.self)
    }

}
```

Comment: The segues are going from a TableViewController to ViewControllers

Comment: shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender: Any?.self), why this line is there?

Comment: you are missing an `else` on your second if statement as well

Comment: it's help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the

let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController

line. This will attempt to cast any VC (including your search VC) as a DetailViewController. Try this:

```
let detailVC : UIViewController

if segue.identifier == "newDocSegue"   {
    // Create a new document and pass it to the detail view.
    detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    detailVC.doc = Document()
    detailVC.isAddAction = true
}

if segue.identifier == "editDocSegue"    {
    // Load the existing document into the detail view, for editing.
    detailVC = segue.destination as! ???  // not sure what type you want here
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
    detailVC.doc = Document[indexPath.row]
    detailVC.isAddAction = false
}
 else if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
    detailVC = segue.destination as! SearchViewController
    shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender: Any?.self)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answered it. I moved the let statement inside of the first two segues.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at:

```
let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
```

if your destination's type is `SearchViewController` cast will cause error

Try this:

```
if let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
```

You should be aware about `as?` and `as!`

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.