# Segue with TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, segue

I have some cell's (image bellow) created by tab[] I need to segue correct value to another view (moreViewController) on this view I have 'nazwa' 'szerokosc' 'dlugosc' and I need to save to nazwa correct "place" from cell etc 
have somebody any solution? I search it but I don't find :/

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "more", sender: tableView)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destViewController:moreViewController = segue.destination as! moreViewController

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nazwaTab.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cellTableViewCell
    let nazwa = nazwaTab[indexPath.row]
    let szerokosc = szerokoscTab[indexPath.row]
    let dlugosc = dlugoscTab[indexPath.row]
    cell.nazwaLabel.text = nazwa
    cell.szerokoscLabel.text = szerokosc
    cell.dlugoscLabel.text = dlugosc
    return (cell)
}
```

[image: IMAGE I CAN't "post images yet "]

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Your issue is not clear. What do you mean by "need to save to nazwa correct "place" from cell etc ?". 
Do you want to get which image/tab was tapped or what?

Comment: Nooo, when I click some cell I need to segue https://scr.hu/BL69P4 to this view, but when I click place 18 "nazwa" must be place 18 when I click place 24 "nazwa" must be  place 24

Comment: @k0le Are you able to move to `moreViewController` when you select cell.

Comment: Check you storyboard identifier of segue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400 try this

Comment: People my segue work fine, but I don't have idea how can I transport "nazwaLabel.text" to "moreViewController"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable `nazwa` in `MoreViewController` and assign a value to it before segueing to it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let identifier = segue.identifier ?? ""
            switch identifier {
              case "more":
                guard let vc = segue.destination as? MoreViewController else {
                  return
                }
                vc.nazwa = self.clickedNazwa
              default:
                break
            }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    self.clickedNazwa = nazwaTab[indexPath.row]        
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "more", sender: tableView)

}
```

Comment: Have u Idea why I have it as "Optional"?

Comment: Its good to have optional. If you dont want it as optional, declare `nazwa` variable in `MoreViewController` with `!` at the end of the type. e.g. `var nazwa: String!`

Comment: I have "var nazwa:String!" but it's steel optional ;d

Comment: You can use the `??` operator to safely unwrap it.

Comment: ye.. I have another question, when I click 1st time on cell "more" is empty, when I click 2nd time it work, but 1st time no why?

Answer (score 0):

You can save a selected row to global variable and use it after call: **prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)**