# Perform Segue From viewDidLoad()

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, segue

I am new to iOS. I have a very similar requirement like my working Android project. The requirement is that in my LoginActivity `onCreate()`, I am checking for some condition and if it is true then I am launching my next Activity using an `Intent`.

I am trying to perform the same functionality form my iOS app. In my LoginViewController `viewDidLoad()`, after checking for some condition, I am calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myNextControllerSegue" sender:nil];`.

But, my ViewController is not changing to next view controller. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: call you segue in main thread or move to viewdidappear or viewwillappear

Comment: make sure you configured the segue in `Storyboard` with the same name `myNextControllerSegue`.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it didn't work if I call it in viewWillAppear(). When I move the logic to viewDidAppear() then it is working but I am seeing a flickering where I can see my login UI too. How to avoid that flicker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: If you find out partway through the presentation of a view controller that you don't want to present it, then you found out too late.  Do the logic that checks your login condition before you committing to a VC, then create the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to perform segue at right place.you are tried to loading another view before first one in hierarchy.So viewDidAppear is called you have a fully loaded view to modify.

```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myNextControllerSegue" sender:nil];
    }
```

To remove that flickering, just hide the view in your `viewWillApear` method.

otherwise as quick search you can do that into main thread also like below

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in   
  //perform segue
})
```

Comment: I am seeing a slight flickering where I can see the old view too. How to avoid that??

Comment: @HelloWorld  just hide the view in your viewWillApear method.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad:` is not used for segue performing. You should call the segue in `viewDidAppear:`, where the view structure is already established.

Answer (score 0):

On your Storyboard, click on your view controller, go to the "Connections inspector" part, and in "Triggered segues", drag the "+" button to the controller you want to reach.

Now click on your segue and go on "Attributes inspector" part, and set "myNextControllerSegue" for identifier.