# Table View (Inside View Controller) Segue Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a table view embedded in my view controller, and I want to be able to setup segues to four other view controllers depending on what cell in the view controller is clicked.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to control+drag a segue from the table view to a view controller.

I believe the relevant section of code would be:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let options = ["Home", "My Account", "Settings", "Support"]

    //MARK: Properties
    var selectedItem: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let selectedRow = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
            selectedItem = selectedRow.textLabel?.text
        }

        if selectedItem == "My Account"{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "classifySegue", sender: self)
        } else if selectedItem == "Settings"{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "otherSegue", sender: self)
        }

    }


}
```

This would be the view and storyboard:
[image: Simulation]
[image: Storyboard]

The problem is the current otherSegue comes from the View Controller and not the Table View itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: do you mean you want to push from the tableview.view only and not from the parent viewcontroller of the tableview?

Comment: Yes, I just want to make it so when I click on a row in the table view, depending on the text in the row, it will perform a specific segue to a view controller that I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to come from the tableView itself. The segue should come from the VC where the tableView is contained.

Your code would still work since your

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "classifySegue", sender: self)
```

is invoking a perform segue from **self** which is your ViewController

**NOTE:** In your didSelect function, you don't need to get the **cell** again, just set your selectedItem to self.options[indexPath.row] since you're only trying to get the text that you pass in the cell initially.

Comment: Do you know why when I click on a cell in the simulation, it doesn't work? I added in the rest of my code for the view controller page, but for some reason the cell doesn't link to the next view controller.

Comment: have you tried to check the value of selectedItem using breakpoints? are they correct? and have you made the segue from VC to the next ViewController as I mentioned?

Comment: I tried to just print("Hello") to the didSelectRow and nothing was printed to the console, so somehow it seems like the function isn't even being called when I click on a row. Putting an override in front of it gave me an error of not overriding any method from it superclass. Is it because I named my tableView "tableView" instead of something else?

Comment: you have to connect your tableView delegate and dataSource to your ViewController in storyboard.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That helped a lot! Why did doing selectedItem = self.options[indexPath.row] work, but the previous if statement setting it didn't work?

Comment: I think it's because the cell.textLabel? is optional, and if your try to print the cell.textLabel?.text, it's either there is no value or it will show  something like, "(Optional)someStringHere"

Answer (score 0):

StoryBoard is not allow segue from tableview because it is not clickable/ have't any action ,So You can make segue from tableView Cell.