# how to add popover segue from UITableViewCell button click in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

> Here i am using popover to a new ViewController from my
>   UITableVIewCell button click but i am getting this error 
>   Main.storyboard: Couldn't compile connection:
>    
>   property=anchorView  destination=>

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableView == self.table_view_one) {
        var cell  = table_view_one.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "first_cell", for: indexPath) as! first_cell
       cell.first_view_time_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Iop_gonio_ViewController.someAction), for: .touchUpInside)
       return cell
    }
}

func someAction() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "first_time_btn", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Answer (score 0):

try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if(tableView == self.table_view_one) {
    var cell  = table_view_one.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "first_cell", for: indexPath) as! first_cell
   cell.first_view_time_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   return cell
}

func someAction(sender:UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "first_time_btn", sender: self)
}
```

But I don't think it is a nice method, you should create a protocol handling such interaction.