# navigating to another controller using segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button when clicked it will go to another controller using segue and its called "gosegue" and i'm sending some value with it ..

here is the error i get when i click on the button:

[image]

and i have doubled checked the segue..

i tried to remove performsegue and just print something and it worked fine!

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

this what i got:

> 2018-05-08 09:33:26.776671+0300[4128:1912882] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<.LongtermorderViewController 0x11dc20e80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key familybtn.'

Comment: You have missed value. Therefore your app is crashed!

Comment: Check your segue identifier on storybored.

Comment: @Mannopson what value?

Comment: @A.Munzer i double checked it! and its correct :(

Comment: @Mannopson can you check my updated post please

Comment: search for `familybtn` in your project, you will find it. It's given in storyboard, but no corresponding IBOutlet / IBAction is declared in swift class

Comment: Check your `familybtn` i think you change its name it will have ! in StoryBord

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Comment: @mrs.bassim Can you provide some information about your `LongtermorderViewController` class. I mean code

Comment: What is the idservice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: try with sender:nil `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"gosegue", sender:nil)` if this is not working then check my answer

Comment: @RatulSharker thank you so much!

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish thank you :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the segue. You might have created an IBOutlet(familybtn) from LongtermorderViewController from the storyboard, then either removed it or modified it, but still the connection remains in the storyboard. That is why the app is crashing. Revisit all the connections of LongtermorderViewController in your storyboard. You will find '!' besides familybtn connection remove it and then build your application. It should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please open your "LongtermorderViewController" from storyboard and check IBOutlet of "familybtn".

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this steps for an error free segue**.If you are in same a storyBoard then you can simply do this -
Take a button in your `firstVC` and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag a segue upto your `secondVC`. Then click on the segue. (the round thing on between two view controller). -

[image]

And set a identifier for that (here `about` is the identifier, you can give any name for this)-

[image]

Here is the code -

```
@IBAction func UserDetailVC(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifierName", sender: sender)
    }
```