# perform segue from programmatically button

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using swift 4

I have a tab bar controller where I created a programmatically button in the middle of the tab bar. Upon button click I want to perform segue and show the next view. I created the segue from the tabar view to the next view and named it moveToNext.

here is the button

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let blue = UIColor(red: 53/255, green: 92/255, blue: 125/255, alpha: 1.0)

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = blue

    button.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .highlighted)

    button.backgroundColor = blue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 32
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    button.layer.borderColor = blue.cgColor
    //button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor


    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)

    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: .white)
    UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: blue)

}


@objc func buttonClicked() {
    print("Button Clicked")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveToNext", sender: self)

}
```

I get the following error

```
'Receiver (<Pac.CustomTabBarViewController: 0x7fc94285be00>) has no segue with identifier 'moveToNext''
*** First throw call stack:
```

Im fairly new to swift and Xcode, and come from java background.

[image]

I think I am performing the segue correctly. Why can't it find the segue and how can I fire it from the button click?

Thanks for taking the time to read this and help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: I have seen that before making this post. I stated that in the story board I dragged across made a segue and named it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the tabbar

Comment: you need to drag segue tab bar to next view controller

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the segue  that you have made, with the source and destination view controllers also in the field, with the Attributes inspector at the right also open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you established the segue? In IB <kbd>⌃-drag</kbd> from the the source controller (yellow icon) to the destination view controller)?
- Have you specified the identifier? Select the segue, press <kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd> and type `moveToNext` in the *Identifier* field.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I thought I specified that in my post. Thats the reason why I am posting as I have done everything right.

Comment: There are a few ways to do that but making mistakes anyhow (for example wrong source object of the segue)

Comment: I got it. There are like 4 tabor controls. I was using the wrong one